# Getting a list of public addresses from block zero

Tags: blockchain, rpc, bitcoin, json-rpc

If I have a local blockchain downloaded, is it possible to use the bitcoin-core rpc commands to query a block?  For example the genesis block to get a list of all the public addresses used in that block? If it is possible, which commands do I need to use?

Comment: did you see the addresses in the vout section from your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58608285/getting-a-list-of-keys-from-block-0

Comment: @JBaczuk, I did.  Do all the same issues apply to the public addresses?  Or is there a simpler cleaner way to get addresses?

Comment: You can get addresses if the scriptPubkeys are addresses (sometimes there are scripts which cannot be encoded into an address). There is not a simpler way that I know of to get that information using bitcoin core json-rpc. That is one reason why people build block explorers.

Comment: @JBaczuk, is there an open source block explorer I can install alongside my local blockchain so I can do public address searches?

Comment: There are, here is one: https://github.com/Blockstream/esplora. See https://github.com/Blockstream/esplora/issues/17#issuecomment-445465668

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two sequenced command - `getblockhash` and `getblock`.

- 1st, getblockhash, take block height, and returns hash of the block
  on specific height in the current main chain.
- 2nd take hash and returns block.

From linux command line to get block #10000, you can run:

```
$ bitcoin-cli getblock `bitcoin-cli getblockhash 100000`
```